# How do I model domestic power demand and identify consumers by their resistive and reactive draw

Tags: power-factor-correction, single-phase, ct

I put a [commercially available 80 A current transformer](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/235178519663?hash=item36c1bb6c6f) on the live tail to my domestic fuse box.  I obtain readings of current draw, supply voltage and power draw.
When an appliance is turned on I am interested to monitor the changes in these values. I reason that the changes in these values are down to the electrical characteristics of the appliance. [ an electric water heater rated at 1 kW should register as an increase in power draw of 1 kWh as a resistive drain and zero reactive component, check? A motorised appliance -- the compressor of a fridge/freezer  -- should show a reactive component?]

I have code which checks the values from the CT and looks for significant changes say at 1% levels. I then calculate the change in resistive, reactive drain and the implied power factor defined by the ratio of these;

When the appliance is turned off I believe that I should see the reverse of these changes in the power components *regardless of other appliances joining and leaving the mix of active appliances*.

Am I mistaken in this belief? I am finding it difficult to detect these reversal events by arithmetic matching of changed real and complex demand against previous events.

Comment: Power is in watts or kW but not Kwh (you appear to be saying kilowatt-hour but it specifically reads as something a bit confused). k is lower case for kilo and W is upper case for watts.

Comment: _"1 kW should register as an increase in power draw of 1 kWh as a resistive drain and zero reactive component"_ 1 kWh is not a power draw but an amount of energy. Power x time = energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you are suggesting is quite valid. It was used some decades ago by a startup company looking to put 'appliance detection' into smart meter products. It didn't really find a commercial market.

You might want to bear in mind the dynamic behaviour of appliances as they start up. For instance, a fridge or freezer will draw a very large VAr while it starts, before settling down to a reasonable power. All appliances will drift in consumption somewhat as they warm up, some more than others. Some appliances will have quite large relative swings of power during operation as backlights or CPUs follow brightness or computation demands.

Your algorithm will have to be quite smart to track all the changes.  It may be easier to train the system on the specific appliances one at a time, rather than try to learn what they are just from looking at the data of a random bunch of them. The latter would be a sort of SLAM-Knapsack problem, there may be a PhD in doing it.

Comment: I have to query the clamp through the Tuya integration on Home Assistant and bandwidth is an issue. So to track the moment-by-moment behaviour of each connected device would require processing power nearer the clamp. There was a startup called Voltaware in the UK offering this